# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So, I've created a controller to add topic in my app, and it stores it in database. The only problem is when I show a view it's giving me ErrorException.

Here is the Topic Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::all();

    $userid = Auth::user()->id;

    $topic = new Topic([
      'user_id' => $userid,
      'title' => $request->get('title'),
      'description' => $request->get('description'),
      'tags' => $request->get('tags')
    ]);

    $topic->save();


    //Creating a loop for each user, send a notification.
     $message_content = "The " . Auth::user()->first_name . " " . Auth::user()->last_name . " just added a new topic. \n " . $topic->title . " \n ";

        foreach ( $users as $user ) {

            mail( $user->email, 'New Topic!', $message_content);
        }

    return redirect('/topics')->with('topics', $topics);



}
```

Here is the view

```
@foreach($topics as $topic)
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="widget widget-shadow">
        <div class="widget-content padding-20 bg-green-500 white height-full">

          <a class="avatar pull-left margin-right-20" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <img src=" {{URL::to('uploads')}}/{{ $topic->creator->image }} " alt=" ">
          </a>
          <div style="overflow:hidden;">
            <small class="pull-right grey-200">{{$topic['created_at']}}</small>
            <div class="font-size-18"> {{$topic->creator->first_name}}  {{$topic->creator->last_name}}</div>
            <div class="grey-200 font-size-14 margin-bottom-10">{{$topic->creator->role}}</div>
            <blockquote class="cover-quote font-size-16 white">{{$topic['title']}}
            </blockquote>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Here is the topic model

```
class Topic extends Model

public $fillable = ['title', 'user_id', 'description', 'tags'];

public function creator() {
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
```

and here is the user model(only relation to topic model)

```
public function hasTopic() {
    return $this->hasMany( Topic::class, 'id', 'user_id' );
}
```

lastly here is the controller that gets the topic data and shows a view

```
public function sdp()
{

    $topics = Topic::all();

    $users = User::with([ 'hasTopic' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', 'user_id');

    }]);


    return view('topics.student', ['topics' => $topics, 'users' => $users] );

}
```

Comment: Provide the error that you getting @ffs33

Comment: [01:44:39] LOG.error: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: I just checked on my localhost it can show the view but on server it wont work

Comment: What is the data format of your `$topics`?

Comment: well $topics is just a reference to the topics table

Comment: Check in your laravel.log file and get the exact line number and file causing the issue. In eloquent relationships, if it's defined incorrectly, you are going to be attempting to get a "property of a non-object". For example, if your "creator" relationship isn't right, you are going to be calling `role` on `null`. Double check your log, and all of your relationships.

Comment: I just can't figure out why is it showing view on localhost, I add the topic I get the view with creator name but on server it shows that error

Comment: Did you look at your log file? It's at `storage/logs/laravel.log`, scroll all the way to the bottom to find your latest error.

Comment: pls check with the no of characters that you are trying to store  and the length mentioned to column bcoz i got the same error while iam trying to store and retrieve excess of char .

Answer (score -1):

You didn't passed the `$topic` variable with your redirect

```
return redirect('/topics')->with('topics', $topics);
```

UPDATE 1:
Can you try like this

```
$topic->created_at
```

Instead of using like array as you have object in `$topic`, not array.

```
$topic['created_at']
```

[Read more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Then how do you pass `$topics` variable to your view, in this controller you just redirect to `/topics` route. Which Controller and Function you are using for the `/topics` route? Error must generate there.

Comment: I just edited my question, can you check above you'll see the view

Comment: To mention that I can see topics posted on localhost but when on server it's showing that error

Comment: Can you share your exception properly? Which object is not found? Line no, File name?

Comment: [02:47:50] LOG.error: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/118696.cloudwaysapps.com/fwzyssdrmj/public_html/storage/framework/views/7bfce097aa53fc730f134b425d87dd73f09bd893.php:21
Stack trace:

Comment: doesnt show which object only which view

Comment: Updated answer. Try it on your all property.

Comment: Just did that, same error

Comment: can you post contents of /home/118696.cloudwaysapps.com/fwzyssdrmj/public_html/storag‌​e/framework/views/7b‌​fce097aa53fc730f134b‌​425d87dd73f09bd893.p‌​hp  especially whats on line 20,21,22

Comment: foreach
              <div style="overflow:hidden;">
                <small class="pull-right grey-200">{{$topic->created_at}}</small>
                <div class="font-size-18"> {{$topic->creator->first_name}}  {{$topic->creator->last_name}}</div>
                <div class="grey-200 font-size-14 margin-bottom-10">{{$topic->creator->role}}</div>
                <blockquote class="cover-quote font-size-16 white">{{$topic->title}}
                </blockquote>
              </div>
             
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        endforeach